# Drawing angles with pgfplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-angles

I would like to put an angle between a curve and a particular axis (let's say the x-axis). I tried several options but chose to use `angles` however it's still not working.

Can somebody help me to identify the problem ?

Script :

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, arrows.meta,
                quotes}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{center} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,
the_angle/.style args = {#1/#2}{draw,<->,
                               angle radius=#1,
                               angle eccentricity=#2,
                               %anchor=south west,
                               }, % angle label position
dot/.style = {circle, fill, inner sep=-1.2pt}
]
\pgfplotsset{ticks=none}
  \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,xmin=0,xmax=15,ymin=0,ymax=7, ultra thick,
    xlabel=$\scriptstyle \log(t)$,
    ylabel=$\scriptstyle \log(R)$,
    x label style={at={(1,-0.01)},anchor=north},
        y label style={at={(-0.15,1)},anchor=west},
        ]
       %
        \addplot+[no marks,blue,domain=0:8,samples=300, thick] {(1/3)*x} coordinate (A);
        \coordinate (O) at (0,0); % intersection with coordinate axis
        \coordinate (C) at (2,0);
        \pic [the_angle=9mm/1.2, $\qty{30}{\degree}$] {angle = C--O--A};
        \addplot+[no marks,dashed,blue,domain=8:14,samples=300, thin] {(1/3)*(x-8)+8/3};
        \addplot+[no marks,ForestGreen,domain=8:14,samples=300, thick] {(1/2)*(x-8)+8/3};
        \addplot+[no marks,dashed,ForestGreen,domain=0:8,samples=300, thin] {(1/2)*(x-8)+8/3};
%
    \node[dot, label=left:$\lambda_{E-G}$] at (0,8/3) {};
        \draw[gray, thick, dash pattern=on 6pt off 3pt] (0,8/3) -- (8,8/3);
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

this option was suggested in this post : [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/665916/draw-angle-between-axis-and-specific-function-using-pgfplots)

and i obtain the following error :

[image]

Thank you for your help,

Sincerely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the `" "` marks:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, arrows.meta,
                quotes}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,
the_angle/.style args = {#1/#2}{draw,<->,
                               angle radius=#1,
                               angle eccentricity=#2,
                               %anchor=south west,
                               }, % angle label position
dot/.style = {circle, fill, inner sep=-1.2pt}
]
\pgfplotsset{ticks=none}
  \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,xmin=0,xmax=15,ymin=0,ymax=7, ultra thick,
    xlabel=$\scriptstyle \log(t)$,
    ylabel=$\scriptstyle \log(R)$,
    xlabel style={at={(1,-0.01)},anchor=north},
        ylabel style={at={(-0.15,1)},anchor=west},
        ]
       %
        \addplot+[no marks,blue,domain=0:8,samples=300, thick] {(1/3)*x} coordinate (A);
        \coordinate (O) at (0,0); % intersection with coordinate axis
        \coordinate (C) at (2,0);
        \addplot+[no marks,dashed,blue,domain=8:14,samples=300, thin] {(1/3)*(x-8)+8/3};
        \addplot+[no marks,green,domain=8:14,samples=300, thick] {(1/2)*(x-8)+8/3};
        \addplot+[no marks,dashed,green,domain=0:8,samples=300, thin] {(1/2)*(x-8)+8/3};

        \draw[gray, thick, dash pattern=on 6pt off 3pt] (0,8/3) -- (8,8/3);
  \end{axis}
      \pic [the_angle=9mm/1.2, "\qty{30}{\degree}"] {angle = C--O--A};
      \node[dot, label=left:$\lambda_{E-G}$] at (0,8/3) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot @codeR it works perfectly : very nice !

Comment: it is off-topic but could I ask you why the node `\node[dot, label=left:"$\lambda_{E-G}$"] at (0,8/3) {};`is not showing up correctly in the generated figure ? thank you in advance

Comment: Your `axis` setup is clippling out the node. Move the line `\node[dot, label=left:"$\lambda_{E-G}$"] at (0,8/3) {};` after `\end{axis}` to make it visible.

Comment: nodes are appearing now but their position in the graph seem totally disrupted (I need them precisely on the coordinates specified)... thank you for your kind help, I think I will open an another post for this issue